# How to Split Document in TexMaker

Tags: formatting

My code is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{report}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{titlesec}


\titleformat{\chapter}[display]
    {\filcenter\normalfont\bfseries}
    {\MakeUppercase{\chaptertitlename}\ \thechapter}
    {0pt}
    {}
\titlespacing{\chapter}{0pt}{-24pt}{24pt}

\titleformat{\section}[display]
    {\filright\normalfont\bfseries}
    {\MakeUppercase{\sectiontitlename}\ \thesection}
    {20pt}
    {}
\titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{0}{0pt}

\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{parskip}
\setlength{\parindent}{.5in}

\usepackage{setspace}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.75} 



\begin{document}

\chapter{INTRODUCTION}
\include{CHAPTERS/Chapter 1}
```

where Chapter 1.tex:

```
\section{BACKGROUND OF THE STUDY}
Here we describe in some detail the use of the package to generate such tables
on a per-chapter basis. The generation of per-section or per-part tables is completely
analogous (using differently named commands); an overview appears at
the end of the section.
```

When compiled it shows:

[image]

Instead of:

[image]

Please help me...

Comment: `\include` always starts a new page: put the chapter heading _in_ the file to be included

Comment: It's best not to have spaces in the file name as well

Comment: Have you tried `\input{filename}` instead of `\include{}`?

Comment: Sir David the file name was the issue. Change it from Chapter 1 with a space to Chapter1 with no space and it solved the problem. I never thought that such a small thing could actually pose a problem. Thank you so much

Comment: @RicardoVelozJr you also need to put the `\chapter` command in the included file, not before the `\include` or you will get a page break after the heading. web2ctex allows you to surround filenames with `"` if it contains problem characters like space, but it's simpler to avoid the problem.

Comment: @David Carlisle I already included the \chapter in the file sir. now both \input{filename} and \include{} works for my document it was the file name that's giving me the trouble.